# SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed after double purchase of any product

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, in-app-purchase

after purchasing the same product for more then one time (consumable or non-consumable).
I get a `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` (not for the first time but for the secon, third etc.)

the error contains following information:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown Error." 
UserInfo=0x101b69c10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
```

The main problem for me is that i cannot pass app store review.
the reviewers say that the application is not working correctly.
The reviewer uses the same account for all the way (already 4 times the app was on review).
I have the same issue, but it is the issue of the Mac App Store server.

May be somebody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was on Apple Sanbox and main Server.
After releasing my app, the in app purchase stopped working totally.
Apple not answering me on this case for nearly a month.

**The only way to fix this was creating new app with new name and new bundle id.**